# mysql load data csv utf8 characters not read, powershell csv export

Tags: mysql, powershell, import, export-to-csv

On a powershell script, I execute a query on an MS Access DB and export the result to a csv file:

```
    $connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= $mdb"
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $q
    $adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $command
    $dataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
    $nb = $adapter.Fill($dataset)

    if ( $nb -lt 1 ){ 
        write-host"empty result !" 
        "empty" | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" $exportxt
    }
    else { 
        write-host "$nb results !"
        $dataset.Tables[0] | export-csv $exportxt -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding "UTF8"
    }
    $connection.Close()
```

When I open this file in notepad++, it shows all characters correctly in utf8 (I have french word in my DB) .

I then upload this csv to a server and execute a php page, which import it to a mysql db using this query:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f'
            INTO TABLE mytable 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES;`

All the tables are in utf8_unicode_ci, but utf8 characters are not well formated (Ã´ instead of ô).

At the end of my php script, I send a confirmation by email with the csv file attached, when I receive it, thunderbird doesn't show the characters neither, but if I open the csv file in notepad++, everything's ok.

It seems the CSV file is not well formated or something like that, what do you think ? I miss an option at the export-csv cmdlet in my ps script ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by specifying utf8 character set in mysql query:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f'
            INTO TABLE article_temporaire_txt 
            CHARACTER SET UTF8 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
            IGNORE 1 LINES`

But why thunderbird doesn't recognize the UTF8 encoding of the file ?